# Finding cousins with Y-DNA

Tags: y-dna, familytreedna.com

My mother's cousin (JEF) has a twelve-marker (Y-12) Y-chromosome test from FTDNA.  Our [earliest **known** common ancestor](https://unigen.us/tree/HHH/individual/P59) (SSF) was born 1817 in Indiana, USA.

The first twenty matches as reported by [FTDNA](https://www.familytreedna.com) are labeled "exact match."  At first glance, I thought some of them were impossible—their "Paternal Earliest Known Ancestor" was born later than SSF and is not one of SSF's descendants.

But then, I thought maybe **one of them has an *unknown* ancestor in common with me and JEF?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

12 markers is not a lot.
What does it show when you click on the "New" Report Clipboard?

[image]

For Y-12 I get quite a broad (1,000 year) range of dates for Most Recent Common Ancestor:

[image]

So the common ancestor could be further back than either tree has identified.

Comment: It is a static chart, so it says the same as your screenshot.  So there may be a common ancestor further back than either party has identified.  Basically, my question was whether that is the explanation.

Comment: Yes, that would indeed mean that you all share the same ancient y-haplogroup but likely have gone on separate branches since then. On your "Ancestral Path" under y-haplogroup it should show your various branches of your y-haplogroup.

Comment: So, for me I'm 
R-M207>M173>M343>L754>L761>L389>...>
BY1058>BY1717>L881>FT13035>A7385>BY32636
and then some more until I'm on my own branch just by myself and nearest offshoot just has 4 others. 

Half of the Western Europe is probably R-M207 and half of the British Isles is DF27 (L881). So both King Tut and I share the same haplogroup which means both he and I descend from an ancient common ancestor (not that he's my direct ancestor).